# Wildcard characters in queries randomly switching between Access * and Ansi %

Tags: ms-access, wildcard, ms-access-2007, ansi-sql

**BACKGROUND:**

I have an Access 2007 application, with a form which builds a Filter string to pass to a Report, which uses a stored query.

In Access Options, I have "SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92)" checked for This database, and the Filter string includes a LIKE clause with % wildcard characters.

**ISSUE:**

Randomly when I save or open the application (not sure the exact cause), the effective wildcard syntax switches from needing % to *, or back.  I know this because my query stops working.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

I do a find/replace on the wildcard characters, it works for a while, and then it happens all over again, without making any significant changes to the query or filter.

Plenty of Compact/Repairs have made no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, I'm not the only one stumped?  Insulting Access on my behalf would at least make me feel better. :7

Comment: Is there some reason you need ANSI-92 syntax? Are you intending to upsize to SQL Server? If so, why bother? I've had no trouble using ODBC and DAO with SQL Server using Access's old "ANSI-89" SQL dialect. I don't know why it's going wrong, but why fight it and not just use what's native to Access, instead of added in as a "compatibility" mode (apparently quite imperfectly)?

Comment: Looks like it "forgets" it's set for ANSI.  I use it for a while, it stops finding with % wildcards.  I change them to *, and it works.  Closing/reopening the application reminds it to use ANSI, and then I have to set the wildcards back to %.

Comment: Thanks for the response, David.  My reason is that I know and like the ANSI SQL syntax.  No upsize intended (but it's always a possibility), so Why Bother? is a good question...  

I guess I don't like old/nonstandard, but I've got enough headaches without being a purist.  Thanks for the pragmatism!

That said, is it an Access bug?  It'd be good to know if anyone else has had similar issues with Access in ANSI mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only using [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HP030704831033.aspx) for the alternative wildcard characters (rather than the enhanced SQL DDL and DCL SQL syntax it offers) then consider using the `ALIKE` keyword in place of the `LIKE` keyword.

The advantage is that you can use the ANSI-92 Query Mode wildcard characters in either Query Mode. The slight disadvantage is that the `ALIKE` is officially unsupported, meaning it might disappear in a future release of the engine (though I would rate this as low risk myself).